# How to use python to control the download file format?

Tags: python, xml, excel, request

I am using python request to download file from website: here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
import wget
import urllib3
import os
import datetime
from datetime import date
import xlrd
my_headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'identity, deflate, compress, gzip',
    'Accept-Language' : 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4',
    'Connection' : 'Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive' : 'timeout=10, max=100'
}
sss     = requests.Session()
r       = sss.get(cs_url, headers = my_headers)
reg     = r'<input type="hidden" id="appIdKey" name="appIdKey"\n\t\tvalue="(.*)" />'
pattern = re.compile(reg)
result  = pattern.findall(r.content)
token   = result[0]
my_data = {
    'commit' : 'Sign in',
    'language' : 'US-EN',
    'appIdKey' : token,
    'appleId' : cs_user,
    'accountPassword' : cs_psw
}
cs_url='https://idmsauth.corp.XXX.com/authenticate'
r       = sss.post(cs_url, headers = my_headers, data = my_data)
print r.url, r.status_code, r.history

PhoneSales_URL='https://aosreports2.corp.xxx.com/sabr/index.php?datetype=week&date_filter=201423&table_break=none&col=metric&aft=Transaction&run=Download&role_filter%5B%5D=1415&role_filter%5B%5D=1437&role_filter%5B%5D=7254&role_filter%5B%5D=7247&role_filter%5B%5D=1423&role_filter%5B%5D=7462&role_filter%5B%5D=4463&role_filter%5B%5D=7461&role_filter%5B%5D=15801&role_filter%5B%5D=17641&role_filter%5B%5D=1430&role_filter%5B%5D=1416&role_filter%5B%5D=1418&role_filter%5B%5D=7463&role_filter%5B%5D=5021&role_filter%5B%5D=1318&segment_filter%5B%5D=Consumer&segment_filter%5B%5D=ED+Ind&dim_select=segment%7Ccall_type%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Cfinance_region&dim_order=agent_geo_t%7Csite%7Cteam_t%7Ccustom_group%7Crole_e%7Crole_t%7Csupervisor_e%7Csupervisor_t%7Cagent_name%7Cagent_ds_id%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Cregion%7Csub_region%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Csite_type%7Crole_group_e%7Crole_group_t%7Cagent_plang_t%7Cfinance_region%7Cpcntry_e%7Cpcntry_t%7Cpregion_e%7Cpregion_t%7Cagent_etype_t&metric_select=fr1usd%7Csal1%7Cbk1%7Csbm1%7Cbk8s%7Csbm2%7Cdc11%7Cdc9%7Cdc12%7Cbk29%7Cbk60s%7Cbk110%7Csal1a%7Cbk144%7Cbk157s%7Cbk3%7Cipad_pp%7Csal1d%7Csbm7%7Csbm21%7Csbm13%7Csbm25%7Cbk108s%7Cbk50&dim_select=site%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Cfinance_region&dim_order=agent_geo_t%7Csite%7Cteam_t%7Ccustom_group%7Crole_e%7Crole_t%7Csupervisor_e%7Csupervisor_t%7Cagent_name%7Cagent_ds_id%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Cregion%7Csub_region%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Csite_type%7Crole_group_e%7Crole_group_t%7Cagent_plang_t%7Cfinance_region%7Cpcntry_e%7Cpcntry_t%7Cpregion_e%7Cpregion_t%7Cagent_etype_t&metric_select=fr1usd%7Csal1%7Cbk1%7Csbm1%7Cbk8s%7Csbm2%7Cdc11%7Cdc9%7Cdc12%7Cbk29%7Cbk60s%7Cbk110%7Csal1a%7Cbk144%7Cbk157s%7Cbk3%7Cipad_pp%7Csal1d%7Csbm7%7Csbm21%7Csbm13%7Csbm25%7Cbk108s%7Cbk50%7Cbk33%7Cbk112%7Cbk45%7Cbk146%7Csal11%7Csal13%7Csal7%7Csal18%7Csal12%7Csal19%7Cbk39&dim_select=site%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Cfinance_region&dim_order=agent_geo_t%7Csite%7Cteam_t%7Ccustom_group%7Crole_e%7Crole_t%7Csupervisor_e%7Csupervisor_t%7Cagent_name%7Cagent_ds_id%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Cregion%7Csub_region%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Csite_type%7Crole_group_e%7Crole_group_t%7Cagent_plang_t%7Cfinance_region%7Cpcntry_e%7Cpcntry_t%7Cpregion_e%7Cpregion_t%7Cagent_etype_t&metric_select=fr1usd%7Csal1%7Cbk1%7Csbm1%7Cbk8s%7Csbm2%7Cdc11%7Cdc9%7Cdc12%7Cbk29%7Cbk60s%7Cbk110%7Csal1a%7Cbk144%7Cbk157s%7Cbk3%7Cipad_pp%7Csal1d%7Csbm7%7Csbm21%7Csbm13%7Csbm25%7Cbk108s%7Cbk50%7Cbk33%7Cbk112%7Cbk45%7Cbk146%7Csal11%7Csal13%7Csal7%7Csal18%7Csal12%7Csal19%7Cbk39&dim_select=site%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Cfinance_region&dim_order=agent_geo_t%7Csite%7Cteam_t%7Ccustom_group%7Crole_e%7Crole_t%7Csupervisor_e%7Csupervisor_t%7Cagent_name%7Cagent_ds_id%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Cregion%7Csub_region%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Csite_type%7Crole_group_e%7Crole_group_t%7Cagent_plang_t%7Cfinance_region%7Cpcntry_e%7Cpcntry_t%7Cpregion_e%7Cpregion_t%7Cagent_etype_t&metric_select=fr1usd%7Csal1%7Cbk1%7Csbm1%7Cbk8s%7Csbm2%7Cdc11%7Cdc9%7Cdc12%7Cbk29%7Cbk60s%7Cbk110%7Csal1a%7Cbk144%7Cbk157s%7Cbk3%7Cipad_pp%7Csal1d%7Csbm7%7Csbm21%7Csbm13%7Csbm25%7Cbk108s%7Cbk50%7Cbk33%7Cbk112%7Cbk45%7Cbk146%7Csal11%7Csal13%7Csal7%7Csal18%7Csal12%7Csal19%7Cbk39&dim_select=site%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Cfinance_region&dim_order=agent_geo_t%7Csite%7Cteam_t%7Ccustom_group%7Crole_e%7Crole_t%7Csupervisor_e%7Csupervisor_t%7Cagent_name%7Cagent_ds_id%7Csegment%7Ccall_type%7Cregion%7Csub_region%7Ccountry%7Cday%7Cweek%7Cmonth%7Cquarter%7Csite_type%7Crole_group_e%7Crole_group_t%7Cagent_plang_t%7Cfinance_region%7Cpcntry_e%7Cpcntry_t%7Cpregion_e%7Cpregion_t%7Cagent_etype_t&metric_select=fr1usd%7Csal1%7Cbk1%7Csbm1%7Cbk8s%7Csbm2%7Cdc11%7Cdc9%7Cdc12%7Cbk29%7Cbk60s%7Cbk110%7Csal1a%7Cbk144%7Cbk157s%7Cbk3%7Cipad_pp%7Csal1d%7Csbm7%7Csbm21%7Csbm13%7Csbm25%7Cbk108s%7Cbk50%7Cbk33%7Cbk112%7Cbk45%7Cbk146%7Csal11%7Csal13%7Csal7%7Csal18%7Csal12%7Csal19%7Cbk39'
filename='/Users/test.xls'
r = sss.get(PhoneSales_URL, stream=False, headers=my_headers)
f = open(filename, 'wb')
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512 * 1024): 
    if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
     f.write(chunk)
     f.flush()
f.close()
r.close()
```

By submit this code, I get a Excel 2004 XML spreadsheet file, which is difficult to handle by python, I am looking for solution to download the file with normal xls or csv format. Can anyone help? thank you.

If helps, I also attach the information from chrome:

Comment: If the site or service doesn't give you an option to download in another format (like via a different link or URL), then you can't _make_ python change the download format. All Python can do is download the binary data of that file, whatever its format is.

Comment: @aneroid, however, in my case, what I downloaded is the excel file in the format of "Excel 2004 xml spreadsheet". Do you know what should I do to download a binary data?

Comment: @aneroid, if open the downloaded file in textpad, we get something as what I described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025320/python-convert-excel-2004-xml-to-csvor-excel

Comment: That's what I meant - you can't change that. Look for a link on the site where you can download it another format. It's the not browser or user who chooses the format, it's the site. Also, as per your other question, look at how you can work with the xml you get instead of trying to _change the download format_.

Comment: @aneroid, below is the Response header that the web return: `Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=SABR_Download.xls
Content-Encoding:UTF-8
Content-Type:application/excel; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 27 Jun 2016 08:45:31 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked`

Comment: @aneroid, thank you. then I need to raise another question on how to transform a Excel 2004 xlm spreadsheet file to csv..

Comment: I think your other question _"Python convert Excel 2004 xml to csv(or excel)"_, already asks that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't _make_ python change the download format. Or any language. It depends on what the site is giving. And since this is not a 'web service' type of request where you can choose your response format (eg xml vs json), the question is offtopic.